# How to increase the number of answers per day?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, site-evaluation

This site has been in public beta (thanks to the efforts of many people) for an year. I was comparing the stats with the Buddhism public beta. We have 5000 visits per day whereas they have only 1000. Despite this large 'footfall' everyday, the numbers of answers per day is quite less. How can this be increased so that the site can be taken to the 'launching' phase?

Comment: What stats are you referring to?  There's no stat in Area 51 called "answers per day".  There is questions per day and percentage answered.  Hinduism.SE has far more questions per day than Buddhism.SE.  But what is true is that Buddhism.SE has a 99% answered percentage, whereas our answered percentage is only 69%.

Comment: Part of the reason for the difference in our answered percentage is the "Keshav Srinivasan effect" :-) See here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/384/one-year-completed-where-do-we-stand#comment1111_384

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: By mixing the questions per day and the percentage answered, I can roughly calculate the number of answers per day. :)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I assume you referenced the wrong link in the second comment.

Comment: No, it is the right link; I was referring to Sai's comment and my response.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Oh, hahaa. Maybe, you should direct your energies to only answering questions for sometime? :)

Comment: "By mixing the questions per day and the percentage answered, I can roughly calculate the number of answers per day."  Well yeah, you can calculate it but I'm not sure it's a very meaningful number.  It would be one thing if there were lots of users who were posting more questions than answers.  But that's not really an issue for us.  (Although it's sometimes true in my case, where I spend a week just posting questions without posting any answers.)  The bigger issue for us is that there are some questions that lots of people answer, and other questions which are largely ignored

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Agreed, the average answer ratio is still low even though some questions are answered by a lot of people. This indicates the need for more answers per day. Ofcourse, there is a need for more ignored questions being answered too.